# How to display xml value on cell in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm fetching the value from xml. What I'm fetching it's working good but I face the problem in displaying the value on a cell. I have to display 6 values on first cell and second cell 4 values how can i do this? Because in my first cell, the value is repeated same on next cell.

This is my cell code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TWeatherParser.h"
@class TWeatherParser;


@interface TWeatherController : UITableViewController {

    UITableView *mTableView;
    NSMutableArray *mImage;
    NSMutableArray *weatherarray;
    TWeatherParser *weather;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *mTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *weatherarray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TWeatherParser *weather;

@end





    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


       TWeatherCell *cell =(TWeatherCell *) [mTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[TWeatherCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        TWeatherElement *newobj = [weatherarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([newobj.icon isEqualToString:@"http://\n"])
        {
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
        }
        else {
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newobj.icon]];
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [imageData release];
        }
        cell.reportdate.text = newobj.currentdate;
        NSLog(@"this is cell1 value:%@",cell.reportdate.text);
        cell.conditionname.text = newobj.conditionname;
        NSLog(@"this is cell2 value:%@",cell.conditionname.text);
        cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",newobj.mintemp,newobj.maxtemp];
        NSLog(@"this is cell3 value:%@",cell.twotemp.text);
        cell.twodirection.text = newobj.wind;
        NSLog(@"this is cell4 value:%@",cell.twodirection.text);
        cell.humidity.text = newobj.humidity;
        NSLog(@"this is cell5 value:%@",cell.humidity.text);
        //cell.reportdate.text = newobj.currentdate;


        //cell.reportdate.text =@"My journey";
    //  cell.conditionname.text = @"raji";
    //  cell.twotemp.text = @"pradeep"; 
    //  cell.twodirection.text = @"harish";
    //  cell.humidity.text =@"23";
    //  cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show different values in different cell then you have to use switch case to detect row index :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

ListDetailCell *cell= [[[ListDetailCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[ListDetailCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
            autorelease];
}

switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
        cell.leadingLabel.text = @"Name: ";
        cell.leadingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LABELS_FONT_NAME_BOLD size:11.0f];
        cell.leadingLabel.textColor = FONT_GREEN_COLOR;

        cell.volInfo.text = volRow.volName;
        cell.volInfo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LABELS_FONT_NAME size:11.0f];
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
        cell.leadingLabel.text = @"Address: ";
        cell.leadingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LABELS_FONT_NAME_BOLD size:11.0f];
        cell.leadingLabel.textColor = FONT_GREEN_COLOR;

        cell.volInfo.text = volRow.volAddress;
        cell.volInfo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LABELS_FONT_NAME size:11.0f];
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
        cell.leadingLabel.text = @"Phone: ";
        cell.leadingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LABELS_FONT_NAME_BOLD size:11.0f];
        cell.leadingLabel.textColor = FONT_GREEN_COLOR;

        cell.volInfo.text = volRow.phone;
        cell.volInfo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LABELS_FONT_NAME size:11.0f];
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
        cell.leadingLabel.text = @"Email: ";
        cell.leadingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LABELS_FONT_NAME_BOLD size:11.0f];
        cell.leadingLabel.textColor = FONT_GREEN_COLOR;

        cell.volInfo.text = volRow.email;
        cell.volInfo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:LABELS_FONT_NAME size:11.0f];
        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"Out of Range ",indexPath.row);
        break;
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: i want know that ow to call forcast day on diffrent cell

Comment: @maulik  i ask this question and here i give my fuul source code please chek here

Comment: How to display current day forecast in 1cell and next forecast in other cell in iphone -this is my other question were i am past my all code please chek

Comment: what i am parsing according to xml file it write or not

Answer (score 0):

Use NSXMLParser and parse the xml file then fetch values by keys and make and make a dictionary and store in your array.

Then your way of code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is good enough to show data. But make change accordingly...

Comment: i done all this thing i creat parser class but my problem is how to show diffrent valueon diffrent cell

Comment: you are accessing different object for each cell then it shows you are showing different value on different cell then now waht you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to identify each cell with unique identifier string like below -

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%d", indexPath.row]];

if (cell == nil) { 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%d", indexPath.row]] autorelease];
}
```

By doing this, you will make tableView able to reuse the same cell created (first time) before either with 6 items or 4 items.